# How to make an EXE file consisting of JAR and JRE

Tags: java, deployment, exe

I have a `JAR` file which runs with a global `JRE` installed on my computer. I need to package this `JAR` with `JRE` into 1 EXE file, so that I can run it on any other computer even when there is no `JRE` installed.

I don't want to use `Launch4j` plugin (because of the unsuitable license conditions (General Public License)) and I don't want to make any installer. I just need simple EXE runnable everywhere.

Comment: License is BSD... http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

This program is free software licensed under the BSD 3-Clause License, the head subproject (the code which is attached to the wrapped jars) is licensed under the MIT License. Launch4j may be used for wrapping closed source, commercial applications.

Comment: @MarcStröbel I was watching maven plugin https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j/launch4j-maven-plugin/1.7.24
Other problem of Launch4j is, that it doesn't package JRE with JAR into 1 EXE. This plugin just creates EXE from JAR. You can however tell which JRE should be used. So it solves just half of my problem.

Comment: did you try jwrapper? https://jwrapper.com/

Comment: @MarcStröbel No I have not tried it. My budget is however not so high to buy the product for $5990.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searching, I figured out that the easiest (and cheapest) way is to make an installer. I use Launch4j with Inno Setup.